# image gallery in MVC with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

Am new to MVC.We have a requirement to implement image gallery display in MVC. Right now i haven't started the implementation part.

user will upload the images and we are showing as a gallery of the uploaded images.requirement is To show the list of images to users.

Initial stage we are Just discussing about what and how to implement. So thought you guys would have a greater idea on this and share suggestions.

Please share links and some best and easy way to implement in MVC with Jquery

Thanks,
Peru

Answer (score 1):

try this one nice image galary with jquery
 http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-Image-Gallery/